# Why do some commands have man pages and other commands use --help?

Tags: man, documentation

Wouldn't it be more consistent if one of these always worked?

Comment: I understand that this might have something to do with cross-platform applications, but I am curious if there are any other reasons

Comment: Reality is worse than you describe: many commands have full documentation in `info` format.

Comment: you should totally make this a [feature-request]...

Comment: @Tobias: tagging something feature-request is for requests to add functionality to the site, and belongs on meta.

Comment: @Tobias++ @Kevin I'm pretty sure Tobias is making a joke ;)

Comment: @Kevin M: just kidding. I meant as a feature-request to the devs of unix/linux software

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it would be more consistent. This has nothing to do with cross-platform and everything to do with developers not writing (wanting to write) documentation. a `man` page is documentation, `--help` is mostly programming in nature. I've also seen the case where man pages didn't exist because the developer didn't know how to make one, or convert the documentation from another format, sometimes this is easily remedied.

I would like to note that I wish *both* always worked.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with [@xenoterracide's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1833/500714) - both would be nice...
I expect `--help` to report functionality and options real short.
I expect `man` (or `info`...) to describe in detail what was previously reported by `--help`, maybe provide some examples, background etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some people do not *like* man pages, and write info files instead (notably GNU).

Comment: Why? And which does `help` use? [Here's the answer.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159817/16521)