# Difference between help, info and man command

Tags: man, documentation, info

I know that these command will help to get syntax and options for commands but my question is that how they differ from each other?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`help` is a bash command. It uses internal bash structures to store and retrieve information about bash commands.

`man` is a macro set for the [troff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff) (via groff) processor. The output of processing a single file is sent to a pager by the `man` command by default.

`info` is a text-only viewer for archives in the info format output of [Texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/texinfo/).

Comment: man is more than a "macro set for the troff processor". -1 for this answer.

Comment: @fpmurphy: Not by much.

Comment: This explains very little.

Comment: This explanation is too simple compared to others.

Answer (score 68):

`help` is a built-in command in the `bash` shell (and that shell only) that documents some of the builtin commands and keywords of that shell. That's an internal documentation system of that shell. Other shells have their own documentation system (`ksh93` has `--help` and `--man` options for its builtins, `zsh` has a run-help helper that extracts information from manuals in other formats). Other commands like `vim` have their own embedded documentation system.

`man` is a system-wide documentation system that provides short reference manuals (pages) for individual commands, API functions, concepts, configuration file syntax, file formats organised in sections (1 for user commands, 2 for system calls...). That's the traditional Unix documentation system.

`info` is another documentation system originating in the GNU project. It's hypertext with links (predates the web). An info manual is like a digital book with a concept of table of contents and (searchable) index which helps locating the information.

There's overlap between the 3. For instance, `bash` being part of the GNU project has both a man page and an info manual. The size of the manual makes the man system not as appropriate for `bash` though. However, the structure of the info manual and index is not very good in `bash` which makes it not as easy to look information in as in other `info` manuals like `zsh`'s. `zsh` manual being even bigger is split into several man pages and also has a good `info` manual with a very good index.

It should be noted that the `info` manual is generated from a `texinfo` format which is also used to generate HTML and printable (PDF/PS) versions. In the case of `zsh` though, the texinfo is generated from another format (`yodl`).

Comment: This is the best answer, congratulations. The accepted one is too terse to be useful, given the general nature of the question.

Comment: also useful: `help help`;
not useful: `man help`.

Comment: @DeNovo, yes, since `help` is a builtin of `bash`. More useful: `info bash help`.

Comment: Note that many GNU (and other) programs mangle/summarize the `*.texi` (i.e., `info`) documentation into `man` pages.

Answer (score 33):

`help` is a `bash` built-in, providing help for `bash` commands only

`man` is the traditional form of help for almost every command on your system, and not only, sometimes also configuration files have their own man page. In Linux distros organized in packages, the relative text is in general provided from the same package providing the command. If you have `bash-completion` you can take advantage from <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see what man pages are available.

`info` is an alternative system to provide manual pages for commands, based on `GNU emacs`. It is provided mainly for `GNU` commands and utilities. It don't seem to be widely adopted from others.