# "man coproc" report error but "help coproc" works (where to find documentation for certain commands?)

Tags: bash, man

I learned that from an instruction:

> Co-processing does two things at the same time. It spawns a subshell in background mode and executes a command within that subshell.

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# coproc ( sleep 10; sleep 2 )
[1] 32508
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# jobs
[1]+  Running                 coproc COPROC ( sleep 10; sleep 2 ) &
```

When I refer to its manual, get an error as feedback

```
root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# man coproc
No manual entry for coproc
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# coproc --info
[1] 32579
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# bash: line 25: --info: command not found

[1]+  Exit 127                coproc COPROC --info
```

`help` works

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# help coproc
coproc: coproc [NAME] command [redirections]
    Create a coprocess named NAME.

    Execute COMMAND asynchronously, with the standard output and standard
    input of the command connected via a pipe to file descriptors assigned
    to indices 0 and 1 of an array variable NAME in the executing shell.
    The default NAME is "COPROC".

    Exit Status:
    Returns the exit status of COMMAND.
```

This's very confusing,
How could I have a big picture of the commands on which manuals I can reach to? How to distinguish them?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18087/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19451/117549

Comment: Use `type` to see what it is, and then pick the manpage to read.

Comment: `coproc` is not a program, it's a built-in command. The manual page is [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html); search for `coprocess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coproc` is a shell keyword in the `bash` shell.  Keywords don't usually have their own `man` manuals but are documented in the shell's manual (in this case in the manual of `bash`, `man bash`).  The `bash` shell also provides a `help` command (in itself, `help` is a built in command) that provides a sort of manual for built in commands and special keywords like `coproc`.

There's another built in command in `bash`, `type`, that will help you distinguish whether a command is external or built in:

```
$ type coproc
coproc is a shell keyword
$ type help
help is a shell builtin
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

For things that are not external commands in `bash` (only `ls` is external in the above example), use `help` or read the `bash` manual (which is usually more detailed than what `help` will show you).  For anything else, use `man`.

Note that the shell may also provide several commands as builtins even though they are also available as external commands. Common examples of these are `echo`, `printf`, `test` and `[` etc., but a shell may in fact provide internal versions of *any* command.  This is usually done for performance reasons or to provide an enhanced version of a command.

Commands that are both internal and external will be documented in both the shell's manual and in an external manual, and they may well work differently.  The `type` command in `bash` will tell you which one will be used and you can force the use of a built in command using the `builtin` command, or an external command by using it with its full path (e.g. `/bin/echo`).

Some commands, like `set`, `read` and `cd` are usually *only* provided as built in commands as they modify the environment of the current shell.  These will be documented by `help` in `bash` and in more detail in the shell's manual.

Comment: For a manual the size of bash's, `info` is more appropriate. `info bash coproc` (and press `,` for the next index entry or follow the link to _Coprocesses_ from the entry for the `COPROC` array variable)