# Convert info/texinfo to man?

Tags: arch-linux, man, info

I prefer to view man pages rather than info.

Is it possible to convert/view the info content in the man format?

E.g. `info -o - --subnodes tar | less` but in a more readable format

I am asking because `man tar` says at the top:

> NOTE
> This  manpage  is a short description of GNU tar.  For a detailed discussion, including examples and usage recommendations, refer to the GNU Tar Manual available in texinfo format.  If the info reader and the tar documentation are properly installed on your system, the command

Comment: @jesse_b I'm on Arch but Ubuntu has the same note in `man tar` (updated)

Comment: Related: [Difference between help, info and man command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19451/237982)

Comment: Hmm, man only says '--checkpoint-action=ACTION Run ACTION on each checkpoint.' but info contains a whole chapter?

Comment: @jesse_b that’s because `info` shows man pages if there’s no actual info file. Install `tar-doc` and you’ll see the difference...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`info2pod`](http://web.archive.org/web/20160312112933/http://cskk.ezoshosting.com/cs/css/info2pod.html)’s `info2man` tool to convert info pages into man pages. See [the Debian package](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/info2man/-/tree/master/debian/patches) for patches to allow `info2man` to work with Perl 5.

Comment: Thanks but the link times out for me...

Comment: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/info2man/

Comment: @jesse_b Thanks, I can't get it to install on arch - says `:: Unable to build perl4-corelibs - makepkg exited with code: 4` even after I installed `sudo pacman -S perl-perl4-corelibs` (arch has perl 5)

Comment: The Debian package has [patches](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/info2man/-/tree/master/debian/patches) which you can use to make the program work with Perl 5.