# Do all built-in programs in Unix-like system comes with a man page?

Tags: man

Do all built-in programs in the Unix-like system comes with a manual page? If not, then please mention some such programs that doesn't have **manual page**

Comment: Interesting project: find all executables in /bin and /usr/bin, and run `man` on each name, and examine stderr. Every section has an introduction like `man -s 1 intro`, and there are various sections up to about 8 for other components (syscalls, standard library, file formats, devices, ...). See `man man` for more.

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in programs"? Man pages exist when developers are willing to provide them, there is probably not much more to say on this - see, for instance,  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1832/315749.

Comment: All POSIX commands have a man page as far as I know. I just declare all non-POSIX commands to be not built in. Done.

Comment: not all built-ins have a man page.  e.g. try `man declare` or `man typeset`.   on my system, the first gets a postgresql man page, `declare(7)`.  The latter gets `No manual entry for typeset`.    bash, however, has built-in help `e.g. help declare`.   IMO it would be nice if there was also a `bashdoc` equivalent to `perldoc` or `pydoc` but AFAIK, there isn't.

Comment: `whatis command-name` will tell you if man pages exist for `command-name`

Comment: I'm surprised why this question is getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

A program gets a man page (or other documentation, for that matter) if someone writes it. Not all programs have a dedicated following willing to put in the work.

The [Linux Documentation Project](https://tldp.org) (and others, notably folks from Debian) have been chipping in to create/update manual pages, the kernel has its own area for [manual pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) documenting its interfaces.

Suggested overall structure is as described [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html). The 'roff format used to write them is quite forbidding, using pandoc you can write in MarkDown and translate to it, for a starting point see e.g. [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/682871/how-to-create-a-man-page-on-linux).

Comment: Thanks for your complements. But I'm surprised why this question is getting downvotes.